# Does obscured vision affect speed?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, movement, vision-and-light

Obscuring mist makes no mention of speed and to my knowledge not being able to see more than 5 feet in front of you has no effect on your movement whatsoever, is this correct?

Answer (score 5):

> Hampered Movement
>
> Difficult terrain, obstacles, or **poor visibility** can hamper movement. When movement is hampered, each square moved into usually counts as two squares, effectively reducing the distance that a character can cover in a move.
>
> If more than one condition applies, multiply together all additional costs that apply.

From PHB p.163 or [SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/movement.htm#hamperedMovement).

Answer (score 4):

The rules on [Hampered Movement](http://dndsrd.net/carryingAndExploration.html#hampered-movement) (*PH* 163) mention that "poor visibility can hamper movement [so that] each square moved into usually counts as two squares." Further, Table 9–4: Hampered Movement has "[d]arkness or fog" as the only examples of poor visibility (*ibid.*).

However, the *Dungeon Master's Guide* on [Fog](http://dndsrd.net/wildernessAndEnvironment.html#fog) doesn't list reduced movement among its effects:

> Whether in the form of a low-lying cloud or a mist rising from the ground, fog obscures all sight, including darkvision, beyond 5 feet. Creatures 5 feet away have concealment (attacks by or against them have a 20% miss chance). (94)

Further, the 1st-level Sor/Wiz spell *obscuring mist* [conj] (*PH* 258) doesn't mention reduced speed among its effects, either, nor does the 2nd-level Sor/Wiz spell *fog cloud* [conj] (*PH* 232).

With this in mind, this DM has *never* played that a creature that can still see—even only 5 ft. in front of it—has its movement hampered, nor has this player been in a campaign where the DM ruled that way. It's entirely possible that movement is *supposed* to be hampered in such circumstances—and that's supported by the rules—, but I've never had a DM put that particular 1 from the *PH* on hampered movement due to poor visibility and that other 1 from the *DMG* on fog together to get that particular 2.

Nonetheless,—maybe because hampered movement is mentioned explicitly by such effects,— a creature that's [blinded](http://dndsrd.net/abilitiesAndConditions.html#blinded) or *effectively* blinded due to environmental circumstances—like being in absolute darkness through which the creature cannot see—*does* find its movement hampered.

Comment: Would you also let them charge or run, if they can only 5 feet?

Comment: @András Yes, but they must stop if they encountered difficult terrain. And, remember, running is typically only in a straight line. Movement—even running movement—isn't plotted first *then* taken but *just* taken.